# React Native: Test app in different resolutions

Tags: react-native, resolution, screens

What I am  doing now is closing and opening different instances of Android Emulator to see **how it works in X resolution**.

Is there a smarter way?

Comment: fastlane automate capturing of screenshots for different screen sizes through UI test cases

Answer (score 0):

If your `react-native` app has a single root [react-native-layout-tester](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-layout-tester) is what you are looking for!

The setup is fairly straightforward and you will have to run it on the biggest device possible (a tablet)

```js
render() {
        return (
            <LayoutTester> // here
                <Provider store={ store }>
                    <Router
                        initialRoute={ this._initialRoute }
                        ref={ this._setRouter }
                    />
                </Provider>
            </LayoutTester>
        );
    }
```

In case your app navigation is handled via `react-native-navigation`, then the setup will be a little complex and you wont be able test the Navbar.